# How to show it is progressing with the effect of lighting in bar chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, loading

> I really want to know how to make it like images below in highcharts.
>   Have a good day.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCVU1.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you haven't provided any relevant code or attempt, but just a vague picture, this question is considered too broad. You also gave a very vague description of how the bar chart works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xrange` series with `partialFill` property: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nhoxj4tk/ or simple `bar` series with `plotBands`:

```
series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    data: [12]
}],
yAxis: {
    max: 20,
    plotBands: [{
        color: 'yellow',
        from: 0,
        to: 20
    }]
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ao3v6h15/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands

Comment: Thank you so much but I asked for the effect of lighting over the bar charts. Sorry I made you confused.

Comment: Hi @Pilsun, Ok, so you need to use `Highcharts.GradientColorObject` interface: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GradientColorObject.html. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qc9evpk2/

Comment: You are so kind. Thank you so much. all of thngs you taught me are very useful for me. But I still need a right answer. I want to lighting flow over the bar chart as when I play video games there are loading bar to start games.

Comment: Hi @Pilsun, I am glad I could help. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cgv7re9m/ and let me know if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Hi@ppotaczek, Thank you so much. I really really appriciate that. The sample is very close to what i meant.But Slightly different but I will try with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have another question. If you do not mind of it. I want your opinions. here is link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716094/how-to-put-shadow-inside-of-bar-chart-in-highcharts